# Uniquely identify Microsoft Office Excel files

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm uploading excel files as a bulk to a web application. When a user uploads excel files, I want to identify whether the file is already uploaded to the application.

It's true that I can use the file name, file path or any other meta properties to identify whether the file already exists. I cannot go that path because the user can upload the same file by changing the meta properties(this is a requirement). What I'm trying is, when a user uploads a file

So I'm trying to find out whether these files contain a unique id to check existence. If it doesn't have that kind of inbuild custom property, is there is a way of setting a custom property while uploading files?  Or does anyone know how to tackle this in a different way? (get/set that unique id in C#)

Note: this application is an Azure cloud-based system. So I don't think we can use plugins to open up the workbook and read properties.

Comment: If you open excel in the File menu Info are the list of properties.  If you click on the Property down arrow there are additional properties.

Comment: Yes. I wanna know how to do that in C# level. I will update the question.

Comment: *whether the file is already uploaded* do you mean exactly the same file (as in byte for byte the same) or  the same data (but not necessarily the same author or same save date)

Comment: If you can't use a plug-in and don't have Excel installed on your server, you can't open the file to check it's properties (without going through unzipping the XLSX content and parsing the XML, anyway). You'll have to resort to something you can check externally, like calculating a checksum or the filename or filesize.

Comment: @rene, the same file changing the name "account_balance.xls" to "monthly_account_balance.xls" or updated content in the work sheet